# PopUpTemplate displaying at wrong place

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

When I click on the point in mapImageLayer the popup is pointing/displaying at wrong place.

```
var mapDataLayer = new MapImageLayer({
  url: sArcgisURL,
  sublayers: [
    {  
      id: sSelectedMapLayer,
      definitionExpression:  "MAP_UID = '"+mapId+"'",
      popupTemplate:{
        title:"Machine Details",
        content:"<b>PIN:</b> 1RW8245GFTX798456<br><b> Dealer:</b> Nortrax <br><b>Engine Hours:</b> 365<br><b>Last Call In:</b> JUly 15 2015"
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wajk1.png

Comment: That is pretty weird .. can you add more context? .. is the service public?

Comment: Is it possible it's a multi-polygon or a corrupted shape?